# Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/main/OptionName: com.sun.tools.javac.main.OptionName

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I am supporting java based Application which using (JSP + Spring + Hibernate). We are using Maven to build the code. The servers where application is deployed is now come under EOSL, so now we need to upgrade the server which will non EOSL. In application we are currently using JDK jdk1.6.0_45
and tomcat 7.0.107.Now I need to enhance the JDK from jdk1.6.0_45 to JDK jdk-11.0.12 but while I am changing the JDK jdk-11.0.12 during project build process I am getting error like "Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/main/OptionName: com.sun.tools.javac.main.OptionName".

Note : While I am switching to JDK 7 then error gone but I need only to run code on JDK 11. Please help me. What are the action I need to take.

Maven version :

```
C:\Users\vtripath\Desktop\4C\workplace\cosmo>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Error:
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project cosmo-core: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/main/OptionName: com.sun.tools.javac.main.OptionName -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Th classes in com.sun.tools are only available in JDK up to JDK 8. If your program need those classes you need to update the program (or if you have the source code modify the parts that use com.sun.tools) or stay at JDK8.

Comment: Upgrade the maven compiler plugin. Howver upgrading to Java11 might not be as easy as you think. Depending on the version of Spring, Hibernate etc. used you also might need to upgrade those as well.

Comment: Ok . Thank you for valuable information I will check and let u guys know. Thank you for help